# Create a Rate for use with Throttler

Tags: scala, akka

Following API doc from 
http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/index.html#akka.contrib.throttle.Throttler$$Rate
I setup a Rate :

```
package akka.test

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit._
import scala.concurrent.duration.{ Duration, FiniteDuration }

object RateTest extends App {

  val rate2 = 1 msgsPer Duration(1, SECONDS)

}
```

But I receive compiler exception :

```
Multiple markers at this line:
◾value msgsPer is not a member of Int
◾value msgsPer is not a member of Int
```

Do I require a separate import ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Try importing

```
akka.contrib.throttle.Throttler._
```